# VM Access to Storage account in different region

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

We have a storage account in West EU region, network access is enabled from selected virtual networks.
There is a VNET A allowed to access to this storage account. VNET A is in peering with VNET B.
We have deployed new appliance in East US region which should use this storage account. This appliance is in VNET B and we can't make it work to access this storage account in EU region.

Should this vnet peering work here?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

> ***Note*** that vnet peering enables communication between virtual network within the same region or the across region if your vnet is is in same region and you deployed new appliance in East US region different region) this will not accessible.

you need to use  ***Global VNET peering, Expressroute or VPN gateway***

I created global vnet peering like below:

Created two virtual networks with regions WestEU and Eastus with different address space

[image]

Create a Virtual network gateway for West Eu and East us like below:

[image]

In Virtual network gateway -> under setting, click connection and Add like below and **same for VNG2**:

[image]

Vnet peering:

[image]

Deployed storage account vnetA is connected successfully like below:

[image]

I deployed a sample new appliance another storage account in East US vnet2 is connected successfully like below:

[image]